# How to prevent admin login popup when using Ditto

Tags: ditto

I use [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) for managing copy paste on Windows.
My issue is when I double click on an item on the list, I get often the Windows login popup requesting admin credentials.

I do not know if I have to run it as admin or what.
I tried with and without (cancel the popup) using admin credentials, but the result is the same, I still get my pasted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because **Elevated privileges** is set to True.
To prevent that you have to set it to **False**.

1. Click right on Ditto icon
2. Options > Advanced
3. Change it to False and Restart Ditto if needed.

[image]

Comment: Yeah! it's working. Muchas gracias.

Comment: yes! That's ben so annoying, I finally decided to investigate